# Background image causes second linear layout to vanish

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout that looks like this

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  style="@style/Splash">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/splash_title" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        style="@style/Splash.H1"
        android:text="@string/splash_title"/>

  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/splash_image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_ftnicon"
        style="@style/Splash.Image"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/splash_powered_by" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        style="@style/Splash.H2"
        android:text="@string/splash_powered_by"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My style looks like this

```
<style name="Splash">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

when I change the background to a drawable, like this:

```
<style name="Splash">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_splash</item>
</style>
```

The second linear layout vanishes completely.  The background image shows and the text view for the title shows.

Comment: does it help to remember that if you set a background image to a view that's wrapping its content, its minimum size will be that of the background image?

Comment: I don't think that really has an effect on this, as the text in question is all using a center gravity.  The text inside the root linearlayout is in the middle as it should, but the other linear layout is not even showing.

Comment: have you tried to see what happens to the inner layout with Hierarchy Viewer?

Comment: What does `"@style/Splash.H1"` refer to?

Comment: I tried a quick test with what you posted and my test is working.  You don't show what Splash.H1 Splash.H2 Splash.Image are.  Also, is the bg_splash a png?  a shape drawable?  Finally are you on 2.x or 3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think is happening.

Your @drawable/bg_splash is a full screen image.

Remember that with styles, all children will inherit the settings of the parent (ie. Splash.H1 will also have the same background as Splash).  This means that the background of all of the views will be set to the same full screen image.  With the layout the way you have it defined, the only view that will show is the "@+id/splash_title" text view.  The linear layout will be forced off screen to the bottom.